# Interactable UITextField above NSTextAttachment

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nstextattachment

I previously developed a Mac app using NSTextAttachmentCell, and applying a NSTextfield to it, so that a textfield would appear above the inserted image. Note that this NSTextAttachmentCell is inserted into an NSTextView.

Now, on iOS, I have tried trying to add a UITextField to a NSTextAttachment, but there is no 'addSubView' method for NSTextAttachment.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I should recreate this on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

`NSTextAttachment` is not a child of `UIView`, so you won't be able to do it directly

perhaps what you are looking for is `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Thanks, but I am referring to a NSTextAttachment that goes into a NSTextView, so UItableView is irrelevant. Will edit my question.

Comment: I was just pointing out alternatives,  I am not sure what you are trying to do here with NSTextAttachmentCells, but that is OSX only. NSTextAttachment is used to apply things like formatting to something like a label,  like in my case, I use it to apply UIImages as text characters in the label,  so instead of NSTextAttachmentCell you need to be using UIView and family for iOS for UI things,  and then grab the attributedText off of those items to do anything with textattachments